# How to calculate Framerate using IVMRWindowlessControl9?

Tags: c#, video, directshow, h.264, directshow.net

I'm working on desktop application and using DirectShow. I'm playing live stream in IVMRWindowlessControl9 control.
i want to calculate framerate at which video plays on IVMRWindowlessControl9 control. how can i do this. i have search
a lot  but didn't get any method or API to calculate Framerate. If anybody knows how can i calculate it plese do reply. i'm using h264 streaming data for rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Frame rate does not have to be fixed.

Your options are:

1. Query media type on video renderer input pin, or an upstream video pin, and check it's [`VIDEOINFOHEADER::AvgTimePerFrame`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) field
2. Use video renderer [`IQualProp::get_AvgFrameRate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd376916%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method to get effective frame rate